Equivalence of fibrations
I know that the for fibrations $P \colon E \to B$ and $Q \colon F \to B$ over $B$ there is an equivalence
$$\mathbf{Fib(B)}(R, P \to Q) \cong \mathbf{Fib(B)}(R \times_B P, Q) $$ natural in $R \in \mathbf{Fib(B)}$. Is this true if we replace $\mathbf{Fib(B)}$ with $\mathbf{Cat/B}$?
would this follow because $\mathbf{Fib(B)}$ is a 2-subcategory of $\mathbf{Cat/B}$? Why is it not a full subcategory?
I know these questions may be too elementary but can someone please explain to me.

Does ${\bf Fib(B)}$ have Cartesian functors as arrows?

Yes between the fibrations

Can you think of a functor $F$ between fibrations $p,q$ which doesn't send Cartesian arrows to Cartesian arrows, but still satisfies  $p=q\circ F$? If so, this will be a $1$-arrow in $\mathfrak{Cat}/B$ which isn't in the image of the inclusion ${\bf Fib}(B)\hookrightarrow\mathfrak{Cat}/B$, proving that the inclusion isn't $1$-full in general.

If say $F$ is a discrete fibration? Do you mean that such a $F$ is not in the preimage of the inclusion?

Even just an ordinary functor?

As long as the functor satisfies the factorization condition $p=q\circ F$, it'll be an arrow in $\mathfrak{Cat}/B$.

You're trying to make the 2-category of categories locally cartesian closed, which it isn't. I see that you are located half way between the Universities of Cape Town and Stellenbosch, in both of which there are well established category theorists. I strongly suggest you get to know them.

Sorry, is your statement related to the adjunction above? Or you just making a general statement?

Principally, I am trying to put you in touch with people nearby who can help you with category theory.  As for cartesian closure of 2-categories of categoies, fibrations etc, I've been round that track, it's very messy stuff and I reallly don't want to go back to it.  But if you contact me by email and explain your research programme I can try to put you in touch with other suitable people.  But I'm not going to continue a discussion using MO comments.

@PaulTaylor My supervisors are from Stellenbosch actually, but what I am doing isn't really their area of expertise. Thanks.
